# Irregular position of page number in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I have a problem with position of a page number in ToC, they are on the left instead of being on the right:

[image: example]

The MWE for such behaviour (don't mind the last word, I had to play with the length of the title):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Regulating two-sided markets of electronic commu}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a defect in the standard printing command for the contents line in `book.cls`.  There is one of these for each level.  By default you get the part title followed by a `\hfil`, stretchable space, followed by the page number.  However, the `\hfil` will be swallowed by tex if a line break occurs at this point.  Here is a replacement for the standard definition:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil\vadjust{}\nobreak\hfil\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}Regulating two-sided markets of electronic commu}{3}

\end{document}
```

The code replaces the `\hfil` by

```
\hfil\vadjust{}\nobreak\hfil
```

This the trick on p393 of the TeXBook: the `\vadjust{}` does nothing, but is not swallowed at a line break, so the `\hfil` afterwards will still be in place.

You might prefer to omit the first of these `\hfil`s.  In the given example the page number will then appear on the same line as the part title.

Comment: what would really look nicer is to have the last word of the title brought down to the second line, but *not* stretching the first line to full width.  the page number looks quite unrelated to anything when it's all by itself.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That is essentially what happens in all reasonable cases I test if I omit the `\hfil` as I suggest at the end.  I say essentially, as usually the word gets hyphenated.

Comment: omitting hyphenation, and setting the text ragged right is a nicety applied in the ams document classes.  we think it makes the entries easier to read as well as looking nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Many many things are nicer in the AMS classes.